# Is this the correct way to use a Command Object in two queries...?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I have used a command object twice in a connection. i wanted to know will it be a problem  while executing...

```vb
set cmd = server.CreateObject("adodb.command")
cmd.Activeconnection= objConn
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO XXXX VALUES(@ww,@ee)"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ww", adInteger, adParamInput)
cmd("@ww") = request.queryString("ww")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ee", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput)
cmd("@ee") = request.queryString("ee")
cmd.execute 

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE xxyy SET RCS='Y', ES='T', OV='N' WHERE ww=@ww"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ww", adInteger, adParamInput)
cmd("@ww") = request.queryString("ww")
cmd.execute
```

Comment: Have you tried executing the code? Also, this isn't ASP.NET or VB.NET - try retagging your question.

Comment: No, `adCmdText` doesn't accepted named parameters `@ww` and `@ee`. You need to use the `?` placehholder, change `INSERT INTO XXXX VALUES(@ww,@ee)` to `INSERT INTO XXXX VALUES(?, ?)` leave the `CreateParameter()` methods the same. Also same applies to the `UPDATE` SQL `@EnrolID` should be `?`.

Comment: My question is do i need to define another command Object i.e cmd for the below query or the same cmd object can be used to execute another query...

Comment: @Papai No, see Keith's [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30304492/692942). Just re-initialize and your good to go no need for more variables.

Answer (score 3):

When reusing a Command object, *all* of its properties/parameters/etc. from the 1st query are carried over to the 2nd query. So the example you provided will throw an error when executing the 2nd query because there will be 3 parameters (@ww, @ee, and @ww again) defined for the command object whereas the query expects only 1 parameter. (There are other errors in the code too. See Lankymart's comment.)

It is safer to reinitialize the command object for each query. Example (including the fixes suggested by Lankymart):

```
set cmd = server.CreateObject("adodb.command")
cmd.Activeconnection= objConn
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO XXXX VALUES(?,?)"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ww", adInteger, adParamInput)
cmd("@ww") = request.queryString("ww")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ee", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput)
cmd("@ee") = request.queryString("ee")
cmd.execute 

'' REINITIALIZE THE COMMAND OBJECT
set cmd = server.CreateObject("adodb.command")
cmd.Activeconnection= objConn

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE xxyy SET RCS='Y', ES='T', OV='N' WHERE ww=?"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ww", adInteger, adParamInput)
cmd("@ww") = request.queryString("ww")
cmd.execute
```

Comment: Absolutely accurate! Excellent explanation as well. You also have the opportunity to use `Refresh()` *(if supported by the provider)* to reevaluate the parameters or use `cmd.Parameters(n).Delete()` inside a `For Next` loop to clear the parameters collection before you start. But as Keith has suggested re-initializing the `Command` object is far simpler.